# Get id of element in RecyclerView and add it in JSON Array as a JSON Object on onClick(), remove the JSON Object if onClick() = false

Tags: java, android, json

I am implementing a contacts app, I made a RecyclerView and am showing all the contacts that I fetched from the API. Now, when I select an item, its id (as JSON object) should be added to a JOSN Array and if I unselect the item then that JSON Object should be removed from the Array. I am able to add the id to the Array but when I select multiple items then I am not able to append the next object to the JSON Array. Similarly, when I unselect an item then that object should be removed from the Array.

Here is my Adapter Class:

```
public class ClientListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClientListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ClientListData> clientListData;
public JSONArray clientArray = new JSONArray();
//public  JSONObject clientObject = new JSONObject();

public ClientListAdapter(List<ClientListData> clientListData, Context context) {
    super();

    this.clientListData = clientListData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.client_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ClientListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ClientListData clientListDataModel = clientListData.get(position);
    holder.clientList.setText(clientListDataModel.getClientName());

    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(clientListDataModel.isSelected() ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
    holder.clientList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clientListDataModel.setSelected(!clientListDataModel.isSelected());
            //holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(clientListDataModel.isSelected() ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);


            //JSONObject clientObject = new JSONObject();
            //JSONObject combinedClientList = new JSONObject();

            try {
                    JSONObject clientObject = new JSONObject();
                    if(clientListDataModel.isSelected()) {
                        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        clientObject.put("id", clientListData.get(position).getClientId());
                        clientArray.put(clientObject);

                if(!clientListDataModel.isSelected()) {

                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    for(int i=0; i<clientArray.length(); i++) {
                        clientObject = clientArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        clientObject.remove(clientListData.get(position).getClientId());
                    }
                }

                //clientArray.put(clientObject);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            Log.e("client id array", ""+clientArray);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return clientListData == null ? 0:clientListData.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView clientList;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        clientList = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_client_list);

    }
}
```

}

As you can see... I am running a loop through my List and adding the Id to JsonObject. But, I am not able to append the next selected item.

Comment: u are creating new JSON object everytime click happens

Comment: @Divyesh do I need to create the JSON Object inside the loop and put it to the JSON Array?, could you give me a more detailed explanation.

Comment: first, make clientArray global to class, and create new json object in click listener. and then add it into array

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, As you suggested I made the changes but still when I select more than one element in the RecyclerView my JSON Array gets overwritten by the new JSON Object. Do you need me to put my Model Class and Activity class as well? I have posted the changes above that I made just now.

Comment: for that , you need to first check if specific id is available in json array or not. if available then remove it/.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, Thank you very much I resolved the issue, but if the onClick() condition is false, then how do I remove the JSON Objects from the array?

Comment: You need to iterate through all item in json array

Comment: I am iterating through the elements in the array @ if(!clientListDataModel.isSelected()) condition but I am unable to remove the elements if I unselect it.

Comment: Best way to do is, do not add/remove item on click. But add submit button. Onclick of that button save clicked ids in json

Comment: Yah, adding a submit button is a good approach but in my scenario if the user selected an item at first and after some time if user decides to unselect that item then that object should be removed from the array. If I add a submit button then even if the user unselects an item, that item will be still there in the array

Comment: No, wrong. Add one Boolean variable in model class. When user click make it true. After that submit button click Check if boolean is true then add that id in array